# Simplify my PHP code : form processing file

Tags: php

I would like to know if it's possible to simplify this part of code in my form processing file :

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['form3_prenom']) && isset($_POST['form3_nom']) && isset($_POST['form3_email']) && isset($_POST['form3_telephone']) && isset($_POST['form3_message'])) {
    extract($_POST);
    if(!empty($form3_prenom) && !empty($form3_nom) && !empty($form3_email) && !empty($form3_telephone) && !empty($form3_message)) {} 
}
    ?>
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You're aware that Processing "is an open source programming language and environment for people who want to create images, animations, and interactions", right?

Comment: @Strawberry that's the most useless comment I've seen this year... This comment will come second I guess

Comment: @giorgio Perhaps you're unfamiliar with the history of this thread.

Comment: a bit :) thought you were referring to the question itself, now I see you've deleted the tag 'processing'. My bad, I didn't say anything!

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` is always set.

`isset` can take multiple arguments.

Once you've checked the variables, there is no need to check them again.

```
if( isset($_POST['form3_prenom'], $_POST['form3_nom'], $_POST['form3_email'], $_POST['form3_telephone'], $_POST['form3_message'])) {
    extract($_POST);
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you but the form is validated although if the fields are empty.

Comment: Why are you not using `<input type="whatever" required />`?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, something like this:

```php
$expected_fields = array('form3_prenom', 'form3_nom', 'form3_email', 'form3_telephone', 'form3_message');

$error = false;
foreach($expected_fields as $field) {
    if(empty($_POST[$field])) $error = true;
}
if($error) {
    echo 'A field is empty...';
}
```

btw: checking for `isset` AND `empty` is not necessary. Quoting the [php documentation](https://www.php.net/empty):

> No warning is generated if the variable does not exist. That means
> empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to !isset($var) || $var
> == false.

Comment: Thank you but my fields are empty in the email I get.

Comment: do you fill in the posted fields using the `$_POST` var, or using the 'extracted' variables? As in my example I didn't use the `extract` language construct (which I would advise against actually...)